# If operator< works properly for floating-point types, why can't we use it for equality testing?

Tags: c++, floating-point, equality

Properly testing two floating-point numbers for equality is something that a lot of people, including me, don't fully understand. Today, however, I thought about how some standard containers define equality in terms of `operator<`. I always see people with problems surrounding equality, but never with the other relational comparisons. There are even [silent versions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isless) of them to use, which include everything except for equality and inequality.

Assuming `operator<` works "properly", unlike `operator==`, why couldn't we do this:

```
bool floateq(float a, float b) {
    //check NaN
    return !(a < b) && !(b < a);
}
```

In fact, I did run a test with an additional overload for doubles, as seen [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c0343d114456b98619eba0985a6cc758-3b440a87a52fe2ae7c853c82f4c5144f), and it seems to have the same pitfalls as comparing them with `operator==`:

```
std::cout << "float->double vs double: " 
          << floateq(static_cast<double>(0.7f), 0.7) << " " 
          << (static_cast<double>(0.7f) == 0.7) << "\n";
```

Output:

> float->double vs double: 0 0

Am I to worry about using *all* comparison operators, or is there some other aspect of comparing floating-point numbers that I'm not understanding correctly?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with equality-comparing floating point values per se. The problem is that the result may not behave as expected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `==`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, and `!=` operators work just fine with floating-point numbers.

You seem to have the premise that *some* reasonable implementation of `<` *ought to* compare (double)0.7f equal to 0.7.  This is not the case.  If you cast `0.7f` to a `double`, you get `0x1.666666p-1`.  However, `0.7` is equal to `0x1.6666666666666p-1`.  These are not numerically equal; in fact, `(double)0.7f` is considerably smaller than `0.7` --- it would be ridiculous for them to compare equal.

When working with floating-point numbers, it is important to remember that they are floating-point numbers, rather than real numbers or rational numbers or any other such thing.  You have to take into account their properties and not the properties everyone wants them to have.  Do this and you automatically avoid most of the commonly-cited "pitfalls" of working with floating-point numbers.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I needed. It didn't click that casting the `float` leaves the extra precision part different from a `double` that had it originally. Thus, one has to be less than the other, and therefore not equal. It's such a shame, too, because it would have made my life so much easier if this had worked :p

Comment: Great question and also great answer. For anyone writing software dealing with money, I use the comparison `if( abs(a-b) < 0.001 )`. Normally, financial systems only go to one-half cent or at the most to one-tenth. Definitely is important to clarify carefully.

Comment: It's very risky to do financial calculations with floating point numbers. Generally it's done with either an _integer_ number of pennies, or with a _decimal_ representation. Either way, you still need to exercise great care.

Comment: @PhilPerry: People who have never done financial calculations really love saying that.  I don't understand why.  Using floating-point for money, as long as you pay attention to what you're doing, is an excellent idea if speed is paramount.

Comment: @tmyklebu, it's riskier to do financial in floating point because of all the numerical processing gotchas that can bite you, compared to integer or decimal. If you _really_ pay attention, and know all the shortcomings of floating point and how to get around them, then you might just be able to pull it off.

Comment: @PhilPerry: Have you ever written financial code?  It's a lot *less* finicky than people seem to think.  Blowing up your runtime by a factor of 100-1000 using arbitrary-precision decimal floating-point so you won't be off by one part in 2^53 is just never a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

When using floating-point numbers, the relational operators have meanings, but their meanings don't necessarily align with how actual numbers behave.

If floating-point values are used to represent actual numbers (their normal purpose), the operators tend to behave as follows:

- `x > y` and `x >= y` both imply that the numeric quantity which `x` is supposed to represent is likely greater than `y`, and at worst probably not much less than `y`.
- `x < y` and `x <= y` both imply that the numeric quantity which `x` is supposed to represent is likely less than than `y`, and is at worst probably not much greater than `y`.
- `x == y` implies that the numeric quantities which `x` and `y` represent are indistinguishable from each other

Note that if `x` is of type `float`, and `y` is of type `double`, the above meanings will be achieved if the `double` argument is cast to `float`.  In the absence of a specific cast, however, C and C++ (and also many other languages) will convert a `float` operand to `double` before performing a comparison.  Such conversion will greatly reduce the likelihood that the operands will be reported "indistinguishable", but will greatly increase the likelihood that the comparison will yield a result contrary to what the intended numbers actually indicate.  Consider, for example,

```
float f = 16777217;
double d = 16777216.5;
```

If both operands are cast to `float`, the comparison will indicate that the values are indistinguishable.  If they are cast to `double`, the comparison will indicate that `d` is larger even though the value `f` is supposed to represent is slightly bigger.  As a more extreme example:

```
float f = 1E20f;
float f2 = f*f;
double d = 1E150;
double d2 = d*d;
```

Float `f2` contains the best `float` representation of 1E40.  Double `d2` contains the best `double` representation of 1E400.  The numerical quantity represented by `d2 is hundreds of orders of magnitude greater than that represented by`f2`, but`(double)f2 > d2`.  By contrast, converting both operands to float would yield`f2 == (float)d2`, correctly reporting that the values are *indistinguishable*.

PS--I am well aware that IEEE standards require that calculations be performed as though floating-point values represent precise power-of-two fractions, but few people seeing the code `float f2 = f1 / 10.0;` as being "Set f2 to the representable power-of-two fraction which is closest to being one tenth of the one in f1".  The purpose of the code is to make f2 be a tenth of f1.  Because of imprecision, the code cannot fulfill that purpose perfectly, but in most cases it's more helpful to regard floating-point numbers as representing actual numerical quantities than to regard them as power-of-two fractions.

Answer (score 1):

The following code (which I changed so it compiles: Specifically the call to `floateq` was changed to `floatcmp`) prints out `float->double vs double: 1 0` , not `0 0` (as one would expect when comparing those two values as floats).

```
#include <iostream>

bool floatcmp(float a, float b) {
    //check NaN
    return !(a < b) && !(b < a);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "float->double vs double: "
              << floatcmp(static_cast<double>(0.7f), 0.7) << " "
              << (static_cast<double>(0.7f) == 0.7) << "\n";
}
```

However what matters for the standard library is that `operator<` defines a strict weak ordering, which it in fact does for floating point types.

The problem with equality is that two values may look the same when rounded to say 4 or 6 places but are in fact totally different and compare as not equal.

Comment: Sorry, the code sample I posted was mainly taken from my test, which was linked to. That has an overload for two floats and an overload for two doubles. I touched up the question to better reflect that and keep the name consistent.

Comment: Regarding the actual answer, shouldn't that bit of fluff however many decimal places in be accommodated for by `operator<`?

Comment: `operator<` is not a strict weak ordering for floating-point types, though, because `!(1 < NaN)` and `!(2 < NaN)` but `1 < 2`.  Transitivity of equality fails.

Comment: @tmyklebu, Is it a strict weak ordering when NaN is not a possibility, though?

Comment: @chris: Indeed it is.

Comment: @Mark, Oh, I just realized that my second comment makes no sense. `operator<<` *does* get that part, and that's why they don't compare equal. I'm not sure why I didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

Float and double are both in the binary equivalent of scientific notation, with a fixed number of significant bits. If the infinite precision result of a calculation is not exactly representable, the actual result is the closest one that is exactly representable.

There are two big pitfalls with this.

1. Many simple, short decimal expansions, such as 0.1, are not exactly representable in float or double.
2. Two results that would be equal in real number arithmetic can be different in floating point arithmetic. For example, floating point arithmetic is not associative - `(a + b) + c` is not necessarily the same as `a + (b + c)`

You need to pick a tolerance for comparisons that is larger than the expected rounding error, but small enough that it is acceptable in your program to treat numbers that are within the tolerance as being equal.

If there is no such tolerance, it means you are using the wrong floating point type, or should not be using floating point at all. 32-bit IEEE 754 has such limited precision that it can be really challenging to find an appropriate tolerance. Usually, 64-bit is a much better choice.

Answer (score -2):

Generally all comparison operations on floating point numbers should be done within a specified precision limit. Otherwise, you may be bitten by accumulated rounding error which is not seen at low precision, but will be taken into account by comparison operators.
It just often doesn't matter much for sorting.

Another code sample which does show that your comparison doesn't work (http://ideone.com/mI4S76).

```
#include <iostream>

bool floatcmp(float a, float b) {
    //check NaN
    return !(a < b) && !(b < a);
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    float a = 0.1;
    float b = 0.1;

    // Introducing rounding error:
    b += 1;
    // Just to be sure change is not inlined
    cout << "B after increase = " << b << endl;
    b -= 1;
    cout << "B after decrease = " << b << endl;

    cout << "A " << (floatcmp(a, b) ? "equals" : "is not equal to") << "B" << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
B after increase = 1.1
B after decrease = 0.1
A is not equal toB
```

Comment: Where is the random past-preicision part of a float stored?  I only see a sign bit, an exponent, and a significand.

Comment: Well, I have to agree that the wording I used is kind of frustrating. Updated.

Comment: The trouble with your updated answer is that you have to pick that tolerance somehow.  It can't be too big, or you'll falsely say that two different things are equal, and it can't be too small, or you'll falsely say that two "equal" things are different.  Picking the tolerance, when it can be done at all, usually requires a careful analysis of the input and the roundoff arising from the computation that you do on that input, by which point it's probably obvious to you that you will need to compare within a tolerance.