# What method is better to check greater than in doubles

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I have this:

```
double a = ...;
double b = ...;
if (a < b) {
    ....
} else
....
```

But I cannot use this approach with floating points (double) because, for example:

```
double a = 5 - 4.9 = 0.999999964;
double b = 0.1;
a < b = true // when it should be false
```

I was thinking in two possible solutions

- The first one using multiplying by a certain number, casting to int and rounding:

  `(int) Math.round(a * 10_000) < (int) Math.round(b * 10_000);`
- Or using an epsilon in this way:

  `double decimaPrecision = 0.00001;
  double max = Math.max(a, b);
  double min = Math.min(a, b);
  return Math.abs(a/ b) > (1.0 + decimaPrecision);`

What approach shall I use? Do you knowa better way of checking this? Do you know any 3pp which does these kind of stuffs?

Comment: +1, Good, fair question. It **always** depends on your particular use case. Could you post up some more context?

Comment: Are you sure that `5 - 4.9` comes out as = `0.999999964`? Please double check that.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera I am not checking that a == b... That's the difference

Comment: @Manuelarte: It's not an important difference.  `<` and `>` and `<=` and `>=` work fine for `double`s.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663430/if-operator-works-properly-for-floating-point-types-why-cant-we-use-it-for-eq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `BigDecimal` for this type of comparison:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("5").subtract(new BigDecimal("4.9")); // == 0.1
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.1"); // == 0.1
System.out.println(a.compareTo(b)); // 0 - they are equal
```

**Output**

```
0
```